# Can humans derive any nutrition from eating the bones of animals?

Tags: physiology, digestion

Bones contain many nutrients like Calcium and phosphorus.

And I'd take a guess that some kind of bones like bones of a chicken(hollow) aren't dense enough to be much of a  problem during digestion.

So,is there any benefit in eating for example say chicken bones?

Comment: Just the actual bone, or the marrow as well?

Comment: The actual bone.I know we derive nutrition by eating the marrow.